# htaccess conditions to redirect variants of directory URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I've dug around without much luck finding a solution.

I have a WordPress MultiSite using sub-directories as "temp" URLs so clients can review prior to mapping their domain name.

The login for the mapped domains is domain.com/ui which works with a redirect in my htaccess.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^$
RewriteRule ^ui$ /wp-login.php? [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

I've also tried this `RewriteRule ^ui(.*)$ /wp-login.php [L,R=301]`

However, when attempting to login to a temp URL as described above it does not redirect.

I would like a solution that disregards sub-directories and for that matter any permalink structure and redirects /ui to /wp-login.php

Here are a few examples.

- http://adopttheweb.com/ui
- http://iemajen.com/emajenwebservices/ui

These are both on the same MultiSite blog. The first has been mapped to a domain whereas the second has not and is simply running at a "sub-directory" of the root / parent site.

Comment: does wp-login.php page  inside the main directory like directory ui

Comment: It's a standard WordPress setup so yes. The file is located at root-domain.com/wp-login.php

Comment: I'm sure there is some manner to make this work using htaccess. However, I also have a similar question that might be a better solution if I can get some insight and an answer - http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/225553/overriding-search-from-plugin

Answer (score 0):

Put the following code at main directory .htaccess file

```
 RewriteEngine On

 RewriteRule ^ui(.*)$ /wp-login.php [L,R=301]
```

You can also do it by PHP by putting  header('Location: path/to/target.php'); at the ui directory index page etc

Comment: I tried the htaccess code referenced in addition to what I shared above prior to your suggestion without success. There is no physical ui directory just as there are no physical directories for any site on the network.

I'll update my question with more specific details.

I appreciate your feedback @Mohammed Elhag